# How to add datatable editor in this table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, datatables

Please help me toHow to install datatable editor to this table.? I searched a lot but could not find proper example which is understandable to me. If you help me out to sort this problem I'm very thankful to you .If there is any alternative solution for my problem than guide me that.Thanks for your time and helping me out.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

            <title>ISSUE</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>table>

    </body>
    </html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to add a little script in order to initialize datatable...basically you need the id of the table and just, well in your case should be  `$('#example').DataTable();`

Comment: @Hackerman will you give me on favour ?

Comment: No problem Bigray!

Comment: @Hackerman Will you connect this table to `datatable editor` , in a simple way Please :(

Comment: Didn't you ask this before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537567/how-to-install-datatable-editor-in-this-table

Comment: i deete that ...